# =IFS formula working in Google Sheets but not Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, ifs

```
=IFS(L83<49.9,"Referral",L83<60,"Pass",L83<70,"Merit",L83<100.1,"Distinction",L83<1000,"Over Assessed")
```

I have the above formula in one of my cells. It works perfectly fine in Google Sheets. However, once I donwload the sheet into Excel/LibreOffice Calc, the cell displays as `#NAME?`. If I then alter the formula by adding a space after one of the IF queries, eg. `=IFS(L83<49.9,"Referral", L83<60,"Pass"...` the formula then works again as intended and removes the error, even if I then delete the previously added space?

Can I use a different formula here that will be more reliable? Or am I doing something wrong that is causing this to happen every time?

Please help!

Comment: LibreOffice Calc is **not** Excel or vice versa. Where are you testing this? And as @SolarMike suggests, a lookup-table could be preferred and is more maintainable.

Comment: Use vlookup() and a data table.

Comment: @JvdV I'm using LibreOffice Calc for testing but another member of the team said the same happened in Excel, haven't tried myself.

Comment: @SolarMike I shall try this, thank you

Comment: @JvdV Vlookup does not seem to work as this is a percentile based query. Unless I make a massive list that covers every percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, even works based on percentile - taken as just numbers:

[image]

```
VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$6,2,1)
```

The vlookup works by not looking for an exact match, which you can have bby putting 0 instead of 1 as the 4th argument.